# Update in action create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have three models,auto, perfil, and user. Each user has their own profile. I need that when you publish a new Auto you can update your profile user if the data are different or change in time. But not as used to update the action in the action create. I use nested attributes.

```
 def create
         current_user.perfil||= current_user.build_perfil
         @perfil = current_user.perfil
         @perfil.update_attributes(auto_params)

         @auto = @current_user.autos.new(auto_params)
          respond_to do |format|
       if @auto.save 
        format.html { redirect_to @auto, notice: 'Auto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @auto }
       else
         format.html { render :new }
         format.json { render json: @auto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
     end
```

Comment: Hi there, what is it specifically you're having trouble with? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you ask is that whenever an "Auto" object is created, "User" profile should be updated if there is some change in the data and you don't want to update in the "Create" method of "AutoController"

What you can do is, in your "Auto" model

```
include ActiveModel::Dirty
```

and define a

```
after_commit :update_user_profile, on: :create
```

in your "Auto" model and in the callback function

```
def update_user_profile

prev_changes = self.previous_changes

end
```

Now using "prev_changes" you can check for appropriate changes and update "User" model accordingly.